# php array not returning on first load

Tags: php, ajax, facebook, json

I'm trying to debug a facebook script that loads a users profile into a form which you can then edit.

The problem is that the script does not return the `$user_profile` array when you first load the page. However, subsequent refreshes of the page return the array fine.

How can I get this array to return on the first load of the page and therefore get the rest of the script to run? Is it an `AJAX` solution, or `JSON`? if so how would i go about it?

Thanks in Advance.

```
<?php
  $is_fb = false;
  $is_linkedin = false;
  $reg_method = $_GET['conn_social'];

  if (isset($_GET['in_uid'])){
    $cur_in_uid = $_GET['in_uid'];
  }

  if ($reg_method == "facebook"){
    $is_fb = true;
  }
  else if ($reg_method == "linkedin"){
    $is_linkedin = true;
  }

  if($is_fb) {
    global $fbconfig;
    $facebook = new Facebook(array( 'appId'  => $fbconfig['appid'],
                                    'secret' => $fbconfig['secret'],
                                    'cookie' => true ));

    $user = $facebook->getUser();

    if ($user) {
      try {
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');

        //the below line is for debugging only - THIS PRINTS ON SCREEN REFRESH ONLY
        print_r($user_profile); 
      } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
      }
    }

    $is_fb_uid_exist = hl_check_fb_uid_exist($user_profile['id']);

    if($is_fb_uid_exist){
      $is_fb = false;
    }

    try{
      $fql = "select name, first_name, last_name, birthday_date, sex, profile_url, hometown_location, current_location, work, activities, interests, music, tv, movies, books, quotes, about_me, website, education, sports, inspirational_people, languages, pic_square from user where uid=" . $user;

      $param = array( 'method'    => 'fql.query',
                      'query'     => $fql,
                      'callback'  => '' );

      $fqlResult = $facebook->api($param);
    }

 }
?>
```

Comment: u really neeed to check hw to post a query in so

Comment: hey its not related to your question but first time i saw a well formatted code! hats off!

Comment: thanks, sorry just accidentally chopped it off when pasting code, now edited.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe problem on the first line..

```
    $is_fb=false;
```

when the page is redirecting this is this evaluating as false?

If yes then this is not executing.

```
   if($is_fb) {
     //Your Code
     //Your Code   
    }
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. Yes i did use a login url. After clicking the facebook button and completing the authentication, i get redirected to the correct page. Its on this page that the array is not returning on first load. If i refresh the page it returns fine...

Comment: @user1917727 I have edited the answer..check it..it might be useful

Comment: Nope, the original $is_fb = false;  $is_fb is set to true when the url is .../register?$social_conn=facebook. The code executes fine and jumps through all the correct hoops up until where i have commented it. At this point the array is not returned on the first load. It returns fine if you refresh.