# FQL query not returning results on first load. Only returns after page refresh

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php array not returning on first load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965848/php-array-not-returning-on-first-load)

Hi this is driving me nuts. I posted in another SO forum before i realised there was a Facebook specific forum, but didnt have much luck. So apologies for re-post.

I have a Facebook login script that accesses the users' profile. it then re-directs to, and populates, a page with a register form with all of their profile information.

This code jumps through all the right hoops, but the problem is that the variable $fqlResult is not being populated the first time the page loads, and therefore the form remains blank.

**If i hit f5, the page reloads, $fqlResult returns the correct data and the form is populated.**

```
  <?php
  $is_fb = false;
  $is_linkedin = false;
  $reg_method = $_GET['conn_social'];

  if (isset($_GET['in_uid'])){
    $cur_in_uid = $_GET['in_uid'];
  }

  if ($reg_method == "facebook"){
    $is_fb = true;
  }
  else if ($reg_method == "linkedin"){
    $is_linkedin = true;
  }

  if($is_fb) {
    global $fbconfig;
    $facebook = new Facebook(array( 'appId'  => $fbconfig['appid'],
                                    'secret' => $fbconfig['secret'],
                                    'cookie' => true ));

    $user = $facebook->getUser();

    if ($user) {
      try {
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');


      } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
      }
    }

    $is_fb_uid_exist = hl_check_fb_uid_exist($user_profile['id']);

    if($is_fb_uid_exist){
      $is_fb = false;
    }

    try{
      $fql = "select name, first_name, last_name, birthday_date, sex, profile_url, hometown_location, current_location, work, activities, interests, music, tv, movies, books, quotes, about_me, website, education, sports, inspirational_people, languages, pic_square from user where uid=" . $user;

      $param = array( 'method'    => 'fql.query',
                      'query'     => $fql,
                      'callback'  => '' );

      //This is returning a blank dataset on the first page load. If you refresh the page, then the array is populated.
      $fqlResult = $facebook->api($param);
    }

 }
?>
```

After this each field is populated with a call that looks something life this

```
 <?php elseif($is_fb && isset($fqlResult[0]['first_name'])) : ?>

    <input type="text" name="hl_first_name" id="hl_first_name" style="width:130px;" value="<?php echo $fqlResult[0]['first_name']; ?>" />
```

Comment: yes, thank you for that. I mentioned it above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supply the access token in the $param, you will get the result in the first load.

```
 $param = array( 'method'    => 'fql.query',
                  'query'     => $fql,
                  'access_token' => ACCESS_TOKEN,
                  'callback'  => '' );
```

Comment: thanks. Still not working though, how do i get the access token? I don't believe ACCESS_TOKEN is set anywhere.

Comment: the acess_token is obtained in the response of the FB.Login (read its documentation); for testing you can copy the access token from here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer . But note that this token will last only for 1-2 hours

Comment: Answered my own question - I got the access token with $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken(); and then stuck that variable when you suggested. Still getting the same results though

Comment: I am assuming that you replaced ACCESS_TOKEN with the access token you just obtained

Comment: yes i did. However, again if i echo the access token at the top of the page, on the first load it does not show. If you refresh, then the access token shows and the form populates.

Comment: Strange, but this is a common issue and I also once had this issue which I get resolved using same.

Comment: I think you are on the right track... I just tried printing the $facebook array. This array also somehow contains the access token. However, the first time the page loads, the access token is a combination of my appid and secret. On page refresh, the access token is correct!

Comment: If you get your access token correct in first go, you'll get the result by fql..

Comment: Ok got it sorted. Had to re-write the whole thing. Looking for someway of posting my final code but seeing as some silly people have closed my post I can't seem to do it.